# Can I dynamically cast a function argument?

Tags: c, function-pointers, void-pointers

I want to implement marching cubes algorithm using c. This algorithm creates a surface from a volume. Sometimes the function will receive a particle array describing the volume, and sometimes it will receive a scalar field function (a function that receives some location and returns some value). Instead of making two separate functions, I want the marching cubes function to receive a void pointer. If the needed method is a surface for particles, it casts the pointer to particles array, else it casts it to a function pointer. This is an illustration of what I want:

```
particle_array* global_par_array;
double (*global_scalar_field)(location);

double value_according_to_par_array(location loc){
        //use the global_par_array and return a value
        return value;
}
double value_according_to_scalar_field(location loc){
        //use the global_scalar_field and return a value
        return value;
}
void marching_cubes(mesh* surface ,void* par_array_or_function, char is_par_array){
//                  ^ need this argument to 
//                    be dynamically casted
    double (*method)(location loc);
    if (is_par_array){
        global_par_array = (particle_array*)(*par_array_or_function);
        method = value_according_to_par_array;
    }
    else{
        global_scalar_field = (double(*)(location))(*par_array_or_function);
        method = value_according_to_scalar_field;
    }
    //do the marching cubes algorithm according to method, changing *surface
    return;
```

I'll call this function form python (using ctypes) where I'll keep track of myself, I mean I'll pass `0` in the `is_par_array` argument if I passed a function casted to void pointer, or pass `1` If I passed a particle array casted to void pointer, is this allowed in c?

Comment: So using plain language, you would like to pass either a function pointer, or a particle array via a `void *` argument type, then cast that argument to its proper type depending on what the value of `is_par_array` is?

Comment: @ryyker Yes, that's what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot reliably use `void*` to hold function pointers. `void*` is the generic *object* pointer type.

More importantly, it doesn't make sense from a program design point of view to use the same pointer/parameter for completely unrelated purposes. The correct way to solve this problem is to step back and re-think the program design.

Some design thoughts:
You *can* use a `void*` to point at any struct, in turn containing any type, so that's one obvious solution. Also, since you use the same function formats, it would be possible to pass the function along as the parameter deciding the function. That is, passing on a function pointer to be used as "callback". In general, it is bad to use global variables, so if we can design that away, all the better.

I have absolutely no idea what the actual program does, but here's a suggested re-design using traditional generic programming in C:

```
typedef double march_cube_t (location, void*);


double march_particle_array (location loc, void* data)
{
  // cast data to a struct or object pointer type specific for this function
  ...
  return value;
}

double march_scalar_field (location loc, void* data)
{
  // cast data to a struct or object pointer type specific for this function
  ...
  return value;
}

void marching_cubes(mesh* surface, march_cube_t* algo, void* data)
{
  ...
  double result = algo(some_location, data);
}
```

Also consider *const correctness* where applicable. If you don't need to modify the data then these should be `const void*`.

Comment: @ryyker Simply put, objects = variables. Object pointers = pointers to variables. Function pointers = pointers to functions.

Comment: They aren't unrelated purposes. I want to use the same algorithm but change how the algorithm evaluates some location (either inside or outside the volume). Anyways I'll change the program design and create two separate functions, thank you!